# Correct usage (or not-usage) of Dispatcher.CheckAccess()

Tags: c#, wpf

In Winforms, all controls have an `InvokeRequired` property, that returns true if I have to call .[Begin]Invoke on the control in order to modify it.

In WPF, there is an apparently similar construct in `DispatcherObject.CheckAccess()` and `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()`, but I am frightened by the `EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)` attribute. When I disable editor browsing like this, I use it to means "You should *not* be doing this. No, really. If this is required solve your immediate problem, you have mis-designed your solution to your overarching problem." On the other hand, the only alternative I've found (and, in fact, my original solution) is `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == 1`. (It's horrible. And it doesn't work in the generic case. I know. It does work for my limited uses, though.)

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.checkaccess%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is silent on the presence of and reasoning behind the `EditorBrowsable` attribute. Does it indeed mean "do not use this", as it would if I had typed it, or does it have some other less prohibitive meaning?

Comment: A couple  of people from MSFT seemed to have replied in this post. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/bd0e6f6c-cadd-48f1-8e1a-163c2f17e4ca/ Seems `EditorBrowsableState.Advanced` may have been more appropriate, but there doesn't seem to be any technical reason as to why it shouldn't be called (at least from that thread).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In WPF, you can call `Dispatcher.Invoke` regardless of your current thread, and it'll handle the call accordingly - if you're already on the right thread, it'll just invoke your code, and it uses `CheckAccess` to handle this behaviour.

For a `BeginInvoke` the thread you're currently on is irrelevant: `BeginInvoke` is always asyncronous, and the order of execution is dependant on the priority of the item you add to the dispatcher's queue.

If you weren't supposed to use the method at all, it wouldn't be public: the intent of that attribute is only to hide the member from mechanisms such as Intellisense and other editor-browsers.  You don't typically need to use `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` yourself, which is probably why it's marked as non-browsable, but the wisdom of this is something we can only guess at (unless Eric Lippert is watching ;-)

In summary: just call `Dispatcher.Invoke` and don't worry about `CheckAccess`.

Comment: I think there is merit to checking thread access to determine which to use.  Having explicit control or performing specific prerequisites based on CheckAccess makes sense in some cases. But making a habit of it is bad, because it'd just be duplicating efforts.  Speaking candidly though, Dispatcher.cs is one of the messiest .NET classes I've ever seen.

Comment: The only downside to this is that you're forced to remember which methods might update the UI and always use `Invoke()` when calling them, as opposed to the check/invoke inside a method which guarantees it always works without you worrying about it

Comment: Dan I'm not sure you are right when you say "... if you're already on the right thread, it'll just invoke your code, and it uses CheckAccess to handle this behaviour." If you look into the source of the Dispatcher class, it seems that it only calls CheckAccess if the DispatcherPriority  is Send. IMO, it is a good idea to create a wrapper class for you Dispatcher, which is useful for unit testing, but you can very easily add CheckAccess for every Invoke call. Calling Dispatcher.Invoke from the main thread has cased some issues for me in the past.

Comment: @Zoman: The source I see on the `Invoke` implementation is that if `this.CheckAccess()` returns true, the invoked action/function is immediately run - if not, then it's marshalled to the correct thread. In particular, within this `if` statement: `if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && priority == DispatcherPriority.Send && this.CheckAccess())` there is a line `callback()` (or `return callback()` in the case of a function with a return value) that will execute the target.

Comment: @Dan I did mention in my comment that it is only checked when the priority is Send, which is the highest priority. It would be very rare to use that priority and other than the if statement you mention, I cannot see any relevant calls to CheckAccess(). So in most cases, CheckAccess() would not be called. Bear in mind though that I'm currently using .NET 4.0 and I haven't checked the latest .NET version, which might have changed.

Comment: @Zoman: I think you edited your comment after I wrote (or at least started to write) my reply. it's important, though, to understand that the `Dispatcher` runs a queue and, if your priority isn't `Send` then your call may not be executed immediately, dependant on the state of the queue. In the context of the original question I'd suggest that my suggestion to just call `Dispatcher.Invoke` is still correct - but it's certainly a worthwhile behaviour that I didn't note in my answer.

Comment: The default `priority` of the `Invoke(action)` method is `DispatcherPriority.Send`. See: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,73e16fb1fb6d2b98

Comment: I'm got crash when call `dispatcher.Invoke(() => .....dispatcher.Invoke(() =>{....}))` . I take alot time to find error because no call stack

Answer (score 0):

I would add:
if you want to mimick the "`If invokeRequired then` ..." 
I would say: do not use "`if Dispatcher.CheckAccess`"
Instead, use:

```
If Me.Dispatcher.Thread Is System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread Then
    Label1.Content = value
Else
    Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf displaymessage), value)
    Return
End If
```

The issue I had was that the CheckAccess was always true, even AFTER the begin invoke...

Nevermind, the following code also works fine:

```
   If Me.Dispatcher.CheckAccess Then
    Label1.Content = value 
  Else
    Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf displaymessage), value)
    Return
End If
```