# Is it mandatary to call CheckAccess() on DIspatcher when performing a method that changes UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a code that sometimes is called from UI thread and sometimes from other threads.

```
    public void Notify(string message)
    {
        if (message == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("message", string.Empty);
        }

        var actions = _invocationList.GetActions(message);

        if (actions != null)
        {
            Unity.Container.Resolve<Dispatcher>()
                .Invoke(new Action(() => actions.ForEach(action => action.DynamicInvoke())));
        }
    }
```

In above example should I add condition with Dispatcher.CheckAccess() and simply run an action without Dispatcher in that case or it's enough just to call an action via Invoke regardless in which thread we are now? Why?

Comment: Just a thought: it might be not the best decision to acquire a `Dispatcher` via an IoC container. You can never be sure which thread this dispatcher belongs to. I would use the static property `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` instead. It will create a `Dispatcher` if necessary, or provide the already existing one.

Comment: It is mostly a code-smell.  Having no idea what thread code is running on is quite unhealthy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct usage (or not-usage) of Dispatcher.CheckAccess()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937902/correct-usage-or-not-usage-of-dispatcher-checkaccess)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a peek at how the `Invoke(action)` method is implemented, you will see that the `checkAccess()` is performed automatically.  So no need for you to do it also.

Here is the relevant portion of the source code from the `Dispatcher` class:

```
// Fast-Path: if on the same thread, and invoking at Send priority,
// and the cancellation token is not already canceled, then just
// call the callback directly.
if(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && priority == DispatcherPriority.Send && CheckAccess())
```

You can see it for yourself by navigating the code starting [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,73e16fb1fb6d2b98).

Comment: Thanks. But if CheckAccess() returns true then besides simple invoking of a callback, it does a lot of other things, such as updating DispatcherSynchronizationContext,  so it works a bit different way.

Comment: @olegk: Yes, it definitely does other things as well, no question about that, but the cost of that is minimal.  Most .NET Framework methods do a bit more than we expect.  But the important part is that, if `checkAccess()` is true, you'll see that it calls `action()` directly.  Otherwise, it adds the delegate to a queue to ensure it gets executed on the UI thread, and that is the perf cost you want to avoid if possible, and the .NET Framework does that for you automatically.

Comment: To be honest, I had a problem with this code when running it without CheckAccess(). I've executed Window.ShowDIalog() from UI thread and received "Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended.", after adding this check the problem was disappeared. It was initial reason to ask this question.

Comment: You might want to mention that the default `priority` of the `Invoke(action)` method is `DispatcherPriority.Send`.